# Rails. If Else and Loops

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I want to do the following in a partial:

```
-if (session[:sort] == "up")
  - event.days.sort_by{|t| - t.created_at.to_i}.each do |day|
    = day.title
    = day.etc
-else
  - event.days.sort_by{|t| - t.created_at.to_i}.reverse.each do |day|
    = day.title
    = day.etc
```

But I do not want to repeat

```
= day.title
= day.etc
```

I tried:

```
-if (session[:sort] == "up")
  - event.days.sort_by{|t| - t.created_at.to_i}.each do |day|
-else
  - event.days.sort_by{|t| - t.created_at.to_i}.reverse.each do |day|
= day.title
= day.etc
```

But it doesn't work.  Maybe I can do it somehow with ternary operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort the events, only reverse them if the required condition is met, then print them out.

```
- sorted_events = event.days.sort_by{|t| - t.created_at.to_i}
- sorted_events = sorted_events.reverse  unless session[:sort] == "up"
- sorted_events.each do |day|
  = day.title
  = day.etc
```

Ideally you would do this sorting in the controller, then just do the display in the view.

Answer (score 2):

It is advisable that you do the sorting logic in the controller and store the output in an instance variable. In the view just do the display thing as:

```
<% @results.each do |result| %>
<%= result.title %>
<%= result.etc %>
<% end %>
```